# MySQL Handshake inactivity timeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handshake

I have my backend written in Express.js (link: https://github.com/uriel285/BackendPortfolio) deployed on Render, and I'm trying to connect it to a MySQL database that I deployed on Railway. I know that the database connection is correct because with the same variables I used in my backend's environment, I was able to connect using the VSC database extension to create my tables. The problem is that for the login, my backend relies on the users' table in the database, which worked perfectly when testing locally. However, now I'm receiving this error:

```
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Handshake.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Handshake.emit (events.js:376:20)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Handshake._onTimeout (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Timer._onTimeout (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:555:17)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at processTimers (internal/timers.js:498:7)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM --------------------
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Protocol._enqueue (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Protocol.handshake (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at PoolConnection.connect (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Pool.getConnection (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Pool.query (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at internal/util.js:308:30
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at new Promise (<anonymous>)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Pool.<anonymous> (internal/util.js:307:12)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at Object.getUserByUsernameAndPassword (/opt/render/project/src/models/usuariosModel.js:7:31)
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM at /opt/render/project/src/routes/admin/login.js:26:15 {
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM fatal: true,
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM timeout: 10000
Nov 23 09:16:57 PM}
```

I've already tried modifying the timeout, but it didn't work

Comment: 'Handshake inactivity timeout' means this is a connection error. You are not getting connected to your database